# Did the Rambam consider all of these men prophets?

Tags: rambam, navi-prophets, anshei-knesset-hagedolah

In his Introduction to the Mishna, Rambam [wrote](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rambam_Introduction_to_the_Mishnah.8.3?vhe=Vilna_Edition&lang=bi) (emphasis mine):

> "Until came the time of the men of the Great Assembly – and they were Chaggai, Zechariah, Malachi, Daniel, Chananiah, Mishael, Azariah, Ezra the Scribe, Nechemiah ben Chakhaliah, Mordechai, Zerubavel ben Shaltiel; and accompanying **these prophets** were the remainder of the hundred and twenty elders..."

Chaggai, Zechariah and Malachi were of course prophets. There are some that consider some of the others to have been prophets, but not all of them, at least as far as I'm aware. Does the Rambam's phrasing of this passage mean that he considered all of these individuals (i.e., the men that he names) to have been prophets?

Comment: Hi @Harel13 are you looking for supports to prove that these personalities were indeed neviim or just support to show that Rambam clearly held them to be prophets?

Comment: @Dov No, just wondering what's the correct understanding of this passage.

Comment: I've seen commentaries point out in other contexts that since the peirush was written in Arabic and translated by others, you really have to understand the original to answer these sort of questions.